# Exponential distribution: Life expectancy of a machine.

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

The probability that a certain machine breaks during the first $370$ hours of its use is $50\%$. How many hours may the machine be used until it breaks with a probability, which at least $85\%$?

I don't know if I solved this right. In my equation, $t$ is the answer to the question?

$$\frac{1-e^{- \lambda .370}}{1-e^{- \lambda (370+t)}} = \frac{0.5}{0.85}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in using the exponential distribution. The first hint is there to tell you how to calculate $\lambda$:

$$1-e^{-\lambda 370}=0.5\implies \lambda = -\frac{\ln(2)}{370}$$

Now, use this lambda to solve for your desired time. Can you solve this part?

Comment: $+\ln2$, not $-\ln2$.

Comment: I also solved this way at first but I wasn't sure. Thank you very much for helping me